# I have uploaded the app on all devices, but it shows "your device isn't compatible with this version" in Play Store

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have uploaded the app to Play Store and when I check the Play Store it is showing "your device isn't compatible with this version".

These are a few details of the app

```
minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 29
    compileSdkVersion 29
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
```

Can you see what can be wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: 1. What Android version are your devices? I see you have min 26 in Manifest. 2. You need to check the Play Developer console for any language or region restriction you may have added inadvertently.

Comment: tested device versions are 10 and 11 @Adinia

Comment: Ok, I see, then I can't help you further on this, you need to check the settings in your Play account. Maybe this can help https://play.google.com/academy/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by making changes to the manifest file.

Make sure to add `android:required="false"` for every "uses-feature" line you add in the manifest - if the app can work without that feature as well.

This has fixed my issue.